# Alternatives for swipe action in mobile

Tags: interaction-design, mobile-application, swipe

I have a view for iphone where user has pin and unpin functionality on the list. Everything is working fine as in the image below:

[image]

My view has been divided into sections,and i want this functionality also in Headers or Sections and seems like this functionality is a bit difficult to acheive...I want some alternative User Experience where on how user can pin and unpin each units or cells.

**The pinned ones are later displayed as summary in another view.**

How can i get this effect on the header *"TableViewHeader"* as in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of using an icon like **edit** over it - when user clicks on the icon show the options at the bottom on a small full width transparent background strip with animation.

I hope you have a mental image of it. I can't upload a sketch at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Much like you swipe left to delete something, you can swipe right to pin/unpin something. This behaviour works very well in many to-do and email apps these days.

[image]

Note that the pin icon designates a pinned item. The icon might even not be necessary as it's obvious due to the color that the pinning action is there.

This would work on any horizontal element you have, including the tableViewHeader. If the tableview header implies that all of the cells need to be pinned, you can just pin all of the cells within that tableview, and then allow the user to individually unpin certain things they don't need.

This is somewhat of a parallel to a "select all in inbox" functionality.